# Access multiple devices in Docker container without --privileged flag

Tags: docker

I have an arbitrary number of devices (`/dev/abc0`, `/dev/abc1`, ...) to use within a Docker container. If I pass them individually to the container with `docker run --device /dev/abc0 --device /dev/abc1` they are accessible. The complication here is that, as far as I know, there is no way to pass all devices `/dev/abc*` into the container.

If I instead mount `/dev` with `docker run -v /dev` I need the `--privileged` flag. I have not found a specific capability to use with `--cap-add` which enables the devices without `--privileged`. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more experimentation yielded a potential solution. Provided the `/dev/abc*` devices have major device number `123`, access to these devices (only) can be provided with:

```
docker run -v /dev --device-cgroup-rule='c 123:* rmw'
```